How to print only parent processes during the snapshot of the current processes report?
I want to list all active processes and describe main features of them in text file by script.
I want to get only parent processes so I can identify if the service exists at all.
But there're cases while any of processes is containered by Docker but has no instance at the "parent machine".
I plan to gather information about containered processes by the separate script launched by main starting script.
So in the snapshot I need to list only parent Docker process with no its sub processes lines (\_).
I also thought about using
systemctl --no-pager list-units

but ps is presented at every machine is subjected to audit.
I've tried using grep -v but it has several flaws.

Would pstree work for you?

@Bog
It has child processes also and I have not found its keys to hide them.

@Bog And if I understood correct it displays only united services. I'd prefer use ps.
